# Is there a Firefox extension to bookmark a link without opening it?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Clicking on a link causes a browser to open it. Ctrl+clicking it causes it to open in a background tab. What I seek is to add it to bookmarks silently without opening and without asking for any user intervention. This would save me tons of nerves. Is there such an extension available for Firefox?

Comment: What about right click - bookmark this link?

Comment: Too much hand and eye job, @Raystafarian. I seek a faster, handier way for this.

Comment: how about drag and drop to bookmark bar?

Comment: It's about creating hundreds bookmarks per day, @Pazis ;-) The bookmark bar is out of the game.

Comment: What I actually do is bookmarking every single Google+ post that catches my eye. First I press +1, then I Ctrl+Click its timestamp to open it in a background tab, then bulk-add all the tabs to bookmarks. The problem is Firefox crashes (on Win7 only, removing extensions doesn't help) on every ~10 Google+ tabs or so.

Answer (score 0):

Right click then "L". This is as short as it gets. If what you are trying to do is add a lot of bookmark from a same page then go for the "multi links" extension : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-links/

Comment: Typing L after an RC requires pressing Enter and opens a dialog box, needless to say this does not qualify. And the extension you have linked to can be handy in many cases but not in the case of mine unfortunately.